# independent multi-threading and sharing data problem

Tags: java, multithreading

**background**

I'm planning to make a scheduler which runs every minutes. Whenever it runs, different target data will be given and each time it might take about 90 seconds to proceed.

**my plan**

The process is like :

```
multiple producers(threads) : 
1. get data from some API
2. using data from 1. parse given data
3. put it into a common queue
```

↓

```
common queue
```

↓

```
multiple consumers(threads) : 
1. get data from the queue
2. call some API
3. then insert into RDB
```

(order of each data doesn't matter)

If I understand right, while user threads are running, main thread might finish earlier and the process will keep running till those user threads finish.

**problem/question**

I want each process has own common queue only for threads which from the same process. Also hope to free the memory of certain queue when each process done.

I mean, is it possible like below? :

1. running process A, only threads from A can access to queue X.
2. running process B, only threads from B can access to queue Y.
3. shutting process A, free the memory of queue X.
4. running process C, only threads from C can access to queue Z.
5. shutting process B, free the memory of queue Y.
6. shutting process C, free the memory of queue Z.

---

This is my first time dealing with multi-threading.
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: You can use: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: @Salil Thanks! When process A,B running, that means there are 2 blocking queues. Are threads from process A can access to blocking queue from process B? and will the blocking queue from process A be free after process A finishes?

Comment: What do you mean by "process" here? Do you mean the actual Java virtual machine processes? Or some internal abstraction of yours?

Comment: Here I meant, my process : producers - queue - consumers

Comment: For example, [2021-19-15 17:07:00] Process A runs [2021-19-15 17:08:00] Process B runs [2021-19-15 17:08:30] Process A finishes [2021-19-15 17:09:30] Process B finishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would design it this way:
Use "Thread Pool" of "Workers" assigned to their own queue.
A "Worker" is a class that extends a Thread and have a private reference to its Queue.   So, the Thread Pool of Workers is actually a group of threads all listening to the same queue.
Then you can define a ProducerWorker that extends a Worker.  These producer workers will handle processing the API and put in their common queue.
Same way, A ConsumerWorker is a worker in a workers pool which handles consuming "tasks" from its common queue it has reference to.
In this design, you have a logical separation of the thread "types" (different workers) so you have a more generic separation not limited to different processes.
This is the design.
To implement you'll need to read about Thread Pool and Extending a Thread.
You can write your own "thread pool" or better use Java's builtin implementation ExecutorService to create pools:
Example:

```
ExecutorService poolAlpha = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
ExecutorService poolBeta = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
poolAlpha.submit( alphaWorker );
poolBeta.submit( betaWorker );
```

Here's a pseudo of how the base Worker should look like:

```
    class Worker extends Thread {
        private Queue myCommonQueue;
        private Runnable myWork;

        // to know when to stop the thread.
        private boolean isRunning = true;

       // Constructor
       public Worker(Queue queue, Runnable work) {
         this.myCommonQueue = queue;
         this.myWork = work;
       }
   }
```

Comment: I'm gonna study ExecutorService part, Thanks!